# How to remove the {} and \" from the resulting array using ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a text string as follows:

```
my_string = 'The {"apples" >> "apple"} {"do" >> "does"} not fall far from {+"the "}tree{"?" >> "!"}'
```

I extract all of the content between the braces { } into an array using the following:

```
my_content = my_string.scan(/\{.*?\}/)
```

The result is:

```
["{\"apples\" >> \"apple\"}",
 "{\"do\" >> \"does\"}",
 "{+\"the \"}",
 "{\"?\" >> \"!\"}"]
```

I would like to have the content as:

```
["apples >> apple", "do >> does", "+the ", "? >> !"]
```

I do this in a very noob(and bad) way as follows:

```
my_content = eval my_content.to_s.gsub('\"','')
my_content = eval my_contents.to_s.gsub('{','')
my_content = eval my_content.to_s.gsub('}','')
```

How can I remove the elements I don't want to include correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
▶ my_string.scan(/(?<={).*?(?=})/).map { |s| s.delete '"' } 
#⇒ ["apples >> apple", "do >> does", "+the ", "? >> !"]
```

On the first step we use [positive lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), on the second one—geting rid of double quotes.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. And thanks for the help on the regex side as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this: it will include every {}

```
/{(.[^}]*)}/g
```

^} - ensures that it won't accept '}' as match inside your pattern and with the last '}' ensures it ends with curly brace.

That way you can get all instances, otherwise with your regex it will listen all closing } as a insider match and only stops at the last }

Comment: Have you ever read the question? Have you tried your regular expression?

Comment: @mudasobwa Have you seen that the person has edited the question repeatedly ? with the first answer, the user came up with modified questions ? What do you actually do in such case , keep answering ? you may not be there on desk when the second question arrives ? what would you feel if someone downvote you on the second question ?

Comment: Oh, I beg your pardon. Frankly, I still can’t get accustomed to this “edit-after-answers-were-given.” Also, please edit the answer a bit so I could retract the downvote.